# Linking ROS library issue using _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, cmake, ros

I'm working in a project which uses ROS and WebRTC.

To build both libraries, I have to define "WEBRTC_POSIX" and "_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0".

However, when I add "_GLIB_CXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" definition to compiler, I get unsatisfied link errors from ROS.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04, ROS Lunar, g++ 6.3 and cmake 3.7.2

Is there any trouble with ROS and std=c++11?

Comment: What are these "unsatisfied link errors from ROS"?

Comment: Adding that definition, it's like ROS libraries were not there. I get "undefined reference to ros::init", "undefined reference to "ros::NodeHandle..." and so on

Comment: Sounds like you are not linking `roscpp`.

Comment: @mikkola at the beginning I thought that as well, but when I remove the ABI definition from cmake ROS is correctly linked, so it could not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Ultimately what I found is that you probably need to use Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo to have to compile cleanly.  The ROS comms don't change too often, so you may be able to run this node on a separate PC or VM.

---

I tried to make it work, but ultimately you have to build all of ROS and replace a lot of the Ubuntu system libraries with custom built versions that have the flag set.

I made it as far as a ROS source install + a custom Boost version.  I gave up when I had to add Log4Cxx.  If I remember correctly, there's a few other dependencies too that you'd need to compile.

Comment: sorry, but where's the solution in answer?

Comment: @Gahan the solution is that you either need to use 14.04 and ROS Indigo where there isn't a different ABI; otherwise, you need to rebuild everything from source including all dependencies, including those that are normally system dependencies since the packages all have the new ABIs in newer Ubuntu versions.  Sorry if this wasn't clear to you from my answer.